# I purchased App APK file and seller told me is 100% editable and can be modify, But All files and folders have their company tag and name on the codes

Tags: apk

I purchased App APK file and seller told me is 100% editable and can be modify,They give me instruction to how to change the App , But after I open the folders  I noticed all files and folders have their company tag and name on the codes.As an example , Layout, all codes have their initials , 
Activity, every single code have their initials and tags like this

```
package in.techware.lataxi.listeners;


import in.techware.lataxi.model.CarBean;
import in.techware.lataxi.model.DriverBean;

public interface AppStatusListener {

void onLoadFailed(String error);

void onLoadCompleted(DriverBean driverBean);
```

Here is my concerns, does it matter if they have their initial on all codes? Unfortunately I am not a mobile app or programming  expert.
What should do ? should completely forget about the app and think of it as lost do to future security problems , or should I pay more to someone to go over the files and change every single codes with our initial and company name ? Please if you are expert help me and instructed  to make right decision.

Comment: This sounds like a legal question, not programming.

Comment: Thanks for responding the legal I don’t have a problem, the license is mine.I guess I question it wrong, what I meant is , it’s is ok and safe to keeping the developers company initials in the code ? Or we have to remove all their names and initials line by line and replace it with our own name?